# How to add different background colours for each droppable element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple drag and drop todo list app using react-beautiful-dnd. However I am unable to know how to change the background colour for each droppable element/ column in this. According to my present output, all 3 columns in my app has the same background colour. I want to have different background colours for each column. I am a beginner for react. Therefore please kindly let me know
how to change the background color for each column.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable} from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import _ from "lodash";
import {v4} from "uuid";

const item = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Clean the house"
}

const item2 = {
  id: v4(),
  name: "Wash the car"
}

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("")
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    //creating 3 columns
    "todo": {
      title: "Todo",
      items: [item, item2]//temporary data valuesa
    },
    "in-progress": {
      title: "In Progress",
      items: []
    },
    "done": {
      title: "Completed",
      items: []
    }
  })

  const handleDragEnd = ({destination, source}) => {
    if (!destination) {
      return
    }

    if (destination.index === source.index && destination.droppableId === source.droppableId) {
      return
    }

    // Creating a copy of item before removing it from state
    const itemCopy = {...state[source.droppableId].items[source.index]}

    setState(prev => {
      prev = {...prev}
      // Remove from previous items array
      prev[source.droppableId].items.splice(source.index, 1)


      // Adding to new items array location
      prev[destination.droppableId].items.splice(destination.index, 0, itemCopy)

      return prev
    })
  }

  const addItem = () => {
    setState(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        todo: {
          title: "Todo",
          items: [
            {
              id: v4(),
              name: text
            },
            ...prev.todo.items
          ]
        }
      }
    })

    setText("")
  }
  //the dragdropcontext is the wrapper for draging elements
  //dropable is the certain area inside the column where u can drop items
  //dragble are the items in the column to be dragged



  //here {_.map(state, (data, key) => { 
    //the above function is used to return the data and key of all 3 elements mentioned under use state() above
    //the key: returns todo,inprogress,and done
    //where as the data returns all the values of the variables within each key
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}/>
        <button onClick={addItem}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
   
        {_.map(state, (data, key) => {
          return(
            <div key={key} className={"column"}>
              <h3>{data.title}</h3>
              <Droppable droppableId={key}>
                {(provided, snapshot) => {
                  return(
                    <div
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.droppableProps}
                      key = {"Todo"}
                      className={"droppable-col"}
                    >
                      {data.items.map((el, index) => {
                        return(
                          <Draggable key={el.id} index={index} draggableId={el.id}>
                            {(provided, snapshot) => {
                              console.log(snapshot)
                              return(
                                <div
                                  className={`item ${snapshot.isDragging && "dragging"}`}
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                >
                                  {el.name}
                                </div>
                              )
                            }}
                          </Draggable>
                        )
                      })}
                      {provided.placeholder}
                    </div>
                  )
                }}
              </Droppable>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The css file

```
    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.App {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.App .column {
    width: 30%;
}

.droppable-col {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.item.dragging {
    background-color: coral;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tag attribute attached to each column called `data-rbd-droppable-id`.

By looking at generated HTML you'll see:

```
<div data-rbd-droppable-id="todo" ... >
  ...
</div>
```

It's generated from `state` keys for every  single column you define there. So, you have `todo`, `in-progress` and `done` values at the moment.

**App.js**

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  //creating 3 columns
  todo: { // <- key `todo` which is attached to `data-rbd-droppable-id`
    ...
  },
  "in-progress": { // <- key `in-progress` which is attached to `data-rbd-droppable-id`
    ...
  },
  done: { // <- key `done` which is attached to `data-rbd-droppable-id`
    ...
  }
});
```

Now you're able to control `background-color` for each column by using CSS below.

**App.css**

```
[data-rbd-droppable-id='todo'] {
  background-color: blue;
}

[data-rbd-droppable-id='in-progress'] {
  background-color: orange;
}

[data-rbd-droppable-id='done'] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-williamson-lu107?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Will do for sure. Another kind help. Will you be able to let me know how to modify individual elements/items inside each column pleasssse?

Comment: Assign `id={item.id}` above `className={`item ${snapshot.isDragging && "dragging"}`}` so you can identify each task by it's id with CSS `[id='id-goes-here'] { ... }`. However this is not practical. If you're going to put some logic for specific tasks you should do that by directly setting `style` prop to your `<div>` which holds your task. There are several ways of doing what you want, but I'm not sure why you would control the look of every single task. It's okay if some tasks contains specific attributes like `selected/completed/assigned` but to control it by `id` doesn't make any sense.